# Qt method call from another class?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qmainwindow, qt-signals

I got two windows(two classes), one window that opens another when i click a button.

then the user inputs something into the newly opened window and then transfer that information to the first window when a button is clicked

The problem is I can't seem to send something to the second window so i can send the user input back to the main window. I read a few places that I should use Q_object but not really sure how that works

I should mention that I am new to Qt and didn't know about the designer there is in qt creator before i was way to ahead with the program.

Hope you have some ideas to how I can do this

edit1:

I should show the relevant code i have

**Mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
//alot of stuff not relevant right now creating different stuff
changeProfile= new QPushButton("ændre valgte profil",this);
profileList = new QComboBox(this);
cProfile = new CreateProfile;
connect(changeProfile,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(ProfileChange()));
}

void MainWindow::ProfileChange()
{
    file pfile(profileList->currentText().toStdString());
    string tempName = pfile.read(light);

    cProfile->setValue(light,tempName);
    cPr

ofile->show();
}
void MainWindow::setProfileList(QString Pname_)
{
    bool found = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (Pname_ ==profileList->itemText(i))
            found = 1;
    }
    if (found !=1)
        profileList->addItem(Pname_);
}
```

**createProfile.cpp**

```
CreateProfile::CreateProfile(QWidget *parent)
    :QMainWindow(parent)
{
//alot of other irrelevant stuff here
saveP = new QPushButton("Save",this);
connect(saveP,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(saveProfile()));
}
void CreateProfile::saveProfile()
{
temp = pName->text();
file pFile(temp.toStdString());
bool lights[2] = {light1->checkState(),light2->checkState()};
if (temp.length() == 0)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"Du har ikke skrevet noget navn ind\n Prov igen","Error",MB_ICONWARNING+MB_SETFOREGROUND);
}
else
{
    pFile.save(lights);
    //call function setProfileList
    this->hide();
}
}
```

If that makes sence, If you need the .h file too i can show them also

I need to call `setProfileList` from the mainwindow in the function saveprofile(there is in createprofile window) or if there is a way i can change the combobox in the wainwindow from the createprofile window?

edit 2:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include "createprofile.h"
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
void ProfileChange();
//some other button clicks
public:
    CreateProfile *cProfile;
    void setProfileList(QString Pname_);
//other irelevant stuff

    private:
    // and some private members
    };
```

**createProfile.h**

```
class CreateProfile : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void saveProfile();
public:
    explicit CreateProfile(QWidget *parent = 0);
~CreateProfile();
//and other stuff there isnt relevant
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [Qt signal-slot mechanism](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), namely:

```
class SecondWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:

    SecondWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(Q_NULLPTR)
    {
        // ...
        connect(secondWindowButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(handleClicked()));
        // ...
    }

public slots:
    void SecondWindow::handleClicked()
    {
        // Gather information from the UI as you wish
        firstWindow->foo();
    }
    // ...
}
```

or, if you have a container class for the windows, you could handle it in there, too, as follows:

```
connect(secondWindow->myButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(handleClicked()));
```

Comment: Hmm not sure you understand exactly what i was trying to do(or then i aint understanding you :) ) i posted my .cpp files to maybe help clear it up

Comment: @Sumsar1812: `cProfile = new CreateProfile(this);` and then `parent()->setProfileList()` from the other class.

Comment: hmm ah i tried that earlier but now with the ()

does give me an error 
`error: C2039: 'setProfileList' : is not a member of 'QObject'`

Comment: I am passing a `QString parent()->setProfileList(temp);`

Comment: @Sumsar1812: have you tried to qobject_cast the return value of parent() to your class? `mainWindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent()) if (mainWindow) mainWindow->setProfileList(temp);`, but the best would be to manage these windows from a container class, really.

Comment: And Im not sure what a container class is? a quick google search tells me that its just a class with in my case 2 other classes ? how can this help me?

Comment: Well, you would not need to parent a mainwindow to another which kinda smells fishy design, and fwiw, it should be only just a quick workaround, but did it work anyway?

Comment: Should the 2 lines be in the `mainfile.cpp` constructor or in the `saveprofile()` method at the end?

Comment: I get an error when trying to add them to the constructor and I can't add them to  `createprofile.cpp` because i havnt #included `mainwindow.h` so it doesnt know what `MainWindow` is

Comment: You are doing it wrong. It should not be in the ctor, but saveProfile. Moreover, forward declaration is your friend against circular dependency.

Comment: i get this error when trying to add it to save profile `C2065: 'MainWindow' : undeclared identifier` and how can i forward declare MainWindow?

Comment: Ok I found a very different way to do this, so I have made a comboBox in the ctor of `createProfile.cpp` and then i have acess to the profileList this way

Answer (score 0):

I found a very different way to do this, so I have made a `QComboBox` in the constructor of `createProfile.cpp` and then I have access to the profileList this way.

Comment: This answer does not make sense to me. You wanted to access setProfileList which is a method. Having a data member in the other class will not really help with that. At this point, I cannot understand your answer I am afraid.

Comment: oh yes but as i said earlier "or if there is a way i can change the combobox..." All this function did was chaning the combobox, and i thought i couldnt acess a member from another class so i ended up making a function to do this for me instead, hoping i could use this function in another class. Hope that makes sence

Comment: OK, I see. I am not still unsure why you have two mainwindows. It sounds peculiar. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am just very new to Qt(and general programming) and before you just told me this I didnt know i had 2 main windows. This was just the way i knew from the first window, so i thought it was basicly the same with the second window :P

Comment: I think you wish to have one main window and then widgets inside.

Comment: But you can make a new window as a widget ?

Comment: Why do you need multiple main windows? Usually, people need one main window, a few widgets and dialogs (which  are also widgets).

Comment: Because it is like a whole new "section" or something like that.
You have profiles, that you can transfer to a microcontrolle. You need to be able to create and edit these profiles. So it made sence to have a window that shows profiles, and have the buttons on it. here is a album how it looks up until now:http://imgur.com/a/MU4bJ

Comment: Can you make those with checkboxes too ?

Comment: I will give you the correct answer because you helped me, maybe not with the problem but i see i wasn't that clear, and I am sorry about that